# Python 3.7: Modelling a 2D Gaussian equation using a Numpy meshgrid and arrays without iterating through each point

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I am currently trying to write my own 2D Gaussian function as a coding exercise, and have been able to create the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Gaussian2D_v1(coords=None,  # x and y coordinates for each image.
                  amplitude=1,  # Highest intensity in image.
                  xo=0,  # x-coordinate of peak centre.
                  yo=0,  # y-coordinate of peak centre.
                  sigma_x=1,  # Standard deviation in x.
                  sigma_y=1,  # Standard deviation in y.
                  rho=0,  # Correlation coefficient.
                  offset=0):  # Offset from zero (background radiation).
    x, y = coords

    xo = float(xo)
    yo = float(yo)

    # Create covariance matrix
    mat_cov = [[sigma_x**2, rho * sigma_x * sigma_y],
               [rho * sigma_x * sigma_y, sigma_y**2]]
    mat_cov = np.asarray(mat_cov)
    # Find its inverse
    mat_cov_inv = np.linalg.inv(mat_cov)

    G_array = []
    # Calculate pixel by pixel
    # Iterate through row last
    for i in range(0, np.shape(y)[0]):
        # Iterate through column first
        for j in range(0, np.shape(x)[1]):
            mat_coords = np.asarray([[x[i, j]-xo],
                                     [y[i, j]-xo]])
            G = (amplitude * np.exp(-0.5*np.matmul(np.matmul(mat_coords.T,
                                                             mat_cov_inv),
                                                   mat_coords)) + offset)
            G_array.append(G)

    G_array = np.asarray(G_array)
    G_array = G_array.reshape(64, 64)
    return G_array.ravel()


coords = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 64), np.arange(0, 64))
model_1 = Gaussian2D_v1(coords,
                        amplitude=20,
                        xo=32,
                        yo=32,
                        sigma_x=6,
                        sigma_y=3,
                        rho=0.8,
                        offset=20).reshape(64, 64)

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5)).add_axes([0,
                                     0,
                                     1,
                                     1])
plt.contourf(model_1)
```

The code as it is works, but as you can see, I am currently iterating through the mesh grid one point at a time, and appending each point to a list, which is then converted to an array and re-shaped to give the 2D Gaussian distribution.

How can I modify the script to forgo using a nested "for" loop and have the program consider the whole meshgrid for matrix calculations? Is such a method possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a solution, numpy is all about array operations and vectorization of the code! `np.matmul` can take args with more than 2 dimensions and apply the matrix multiplication on the last two axes only (and this calculation in parallel over the others axes). However, making sure of the right axes order can get tricky.

Here is your edited code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Gaussian2D_v1(coords,  # x and y coordinates for each image.
                  amplitude=1,  # Highest intensity in image.
                  xo=0,  # x-coordinate of peak centre.
                  yo=0,  # y-coordinate of peak centre.
                  sigma_x=1,  # Standard deviation in x.
                  sigma_y=1,  # Standard deviation in y.
                  rho=0,  # Correlation coefficient.
                  offset=0):  # Offset from zero (background radiation).
    x, y = coords

    xo = float(xo)
    yo = float(yo)

    # Create covariance matrix
    mat_cov = [[sigma_x**2, rho * sigma_x * sigma_y],
               [rho * sigma_x * sigma_y, sigma_y**2]]
    mat_cov = np.asarray(mat_cov)
    # Find its inverse
    mat_cov_inv = np.linalg.inv(mat_cov)

    # PB We stack the coordinates along the last axis
    mat_coords = np.stack((x - xo, y - yo), axis=-1)

    G = amplitude * np.exp(-0.5*np.matmul(np.matmul(mat_coords[:, :, np.newaxis, :],
                                                    mat_cov_inv),
                                          mat_coords[..., np.newaxis])) + offset
    return G.squeeze()



coords = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 64), np.arange(0, 64))
model_1 = Gaussian2D_v1(coords,
                        amplitude=20,
                        xo=32,
                        yo=32,
                        sigma_x=6,
                        sigma_y=3,
                        rho=0.8,
                        offset=20)
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5)).add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
plt.contourf(model_1)
```

So, the equation is exp(-0.5 *  (X - µ)' Cinv (X - µ) ), where X is our coordinate matrix, µ the mean (x0, y0) and Cinv the inverse covariance matrix (and ' is a transpose). In the code, I stack both meshgrids to a new matrix so that: `mat_coords` has a shape of (Ny, Nx, 2). In the first `np.matmul` call, I add a new axis so that the shapes go like :(Ny, Nx, 1, 2) * (2, 2) = (Ny, Nx, 1, 2). As you see, the matrix multiplication is done on the two last axes, in parallel on the other. Then, I add a new axis so that: (Ny, Nx, 1, 2) * (Ny, Nx, 2, 1) = (Ny, Nx, 1, 1).
The `np.squeeze()` call returns a version without the two last singleton axes.

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply! I've just had a play with the code, and it runs beautifully. However, my understanding of np.stack, np.matmul, and np.squeeze is still poor. 

If I've understood it correctly, np.stack puts the x and y grids on top of one another to create 64 x 64 sets of coordinate pairs. 

When you use np.newaxis(), are you manipulating how the coordinate pairs in that 64 x 64 meshgrid are laid out (row vector format and column vector format)? 

Lastly, does this mean np.matmul only handles two-dimensional operations in the last two axes? 

Thanks!

Comment: Your understanding of np.stack() is good!  Using np.newaxis does act as some kind of transpose in our case here, by adding a length-1 axis a the good place so that the matrix of the last 2 axes is either row or column. And yes, np.matmul only acts on the two last axes, calling it with higher dimensions arrays is the same as iterating over those higher dimensions and re-stacking the result (like you did before).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I still find the implementation of the ```np.newaxis``` function difficult to visualise. Let's say we zoom in on one of the points in the 64 x 64 array. If we do ```mat_coords[:, :, np.newaxis, :]```, would it be correct to say that the two values become grouped as ```[1, 2]``` (row vector), whereas with ```mat_coords[:, :, :, np.newaxis]```, it becomes instead ```[[1], [2]]``` (column vector)? I hope to hear back from you soon!

Comment: As far as I understand your example, yes! Small fix, the first case, `mat_coords[i, j, np.newaxis, :]` would rather be `[ [ 1, 2 ] ]`, a (1, 2) shape. (Also, for your own knowledge, `np.newaxis` is an explicit version of it, but it evaluates to `None`, thus `mat_coords[i, j, None, :]` has the exact same effet, just less clear).

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you for explaining it to me in such approachable terms, as well as for showing me how ```None``` can be used for array manipulation as well. I really appreciate the time you've taken to do so.